# maven issue : Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

A maven build showing me below error: any help to fix it ?
Below is version

```
 mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.5.0.8-2.el8.x86_64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.0-326.el8.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"



[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

The pom stops below is where it stuck in DEBUG :

```
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
```

and I tried creating settings.xml with correct proxy but never helped. wget works fine from bvelow location : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

So I am sure its not proxy issue and other packages copied fine.
Any idea ?

Comment: Can you please share pom.xml

Comment: This `Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Name or service not known ` looks like a network/firewall/proxy issue...

Comment: @RohitAgarwal -emoving the attribute value ... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId></groupId>   <artifactId></artifactId><version></version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name></name>  <description></description><url></url>
  <properties>  </properties>
  <repositories>    
  </repositories>